# Why does AsEnumerable not work when using FromSqlRaw

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently creating a site that showcases all my patients within a data table and I have to use FromSqlRaw in order to get the data from my database. I have a search funtion that allows me to search the patients within the table but upon entering the page I get this error when I use AsQueryable and no data is displayed in the table. It recommends me to use AsEnumerable but when I do I get an intellisense error. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
          public async Task<IActionResult> Search(StaySearchViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.Cleared)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                draw = model.Draw,
                data = new object[] { },
                recordsFiltered = 0,
                recordsTotal = 0,
                total = 0
            });
        }

        var records = getSearchData(model);
            //var records = System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable(getSearchData(model)); // Hard coding this an enumerable will  break line 55, 57, and 64
            //Sorting
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SortOrder))

                records = records.OrderBy(model.SortOrder);

            var count = await records.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            records = records.Skip(model.Start);
            if (model.Length != -1) records = records.Take(model.Length);


            // Create models
            var result = new List<SpStaySearchResultViewModel>();
        try
        {
            await records.ForEachAsync(r =>
            {
                result.Add(new SpStaySearchResultViewModel()
                {
                    BuildingName = r.BuildingName,
                    CaseManager = r.CaseManager,
                    CaseManagerId = r.CaseManagerId,
                    OccupantFileAs = r.OccupantFileAs,
                    StayOCFSNumber = r.StayOCFSNumber,
                    StayId = r.StayId,
                    MaxOfBillSentDate = r.MaxOfBillSentDate,
                    CountOfChildren = r.CountOfChildren,
                    StartDate = r.StartDate,
                    EndDate = r.EndDate,
                    OccupantId = r.OccupantId,
                    IsActive = r.IsActive,


                });
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
            return Json(new
            {
                draw = model.Draw,
                data = result,
                recordsFiltered = count,
                recordsTotal = count,
            });

    }
    private IQueryable<spStaysSearch> getSearchData(StaySearchViewModel model)
    {

            var records = db.SpStaySearches.FromSqlRaw("dbo.spStaysSearch").AsQueryable();

            if (model.OccupantId.HasValue)
                records = records.Where(x => x.OccupantId == model.OccupantId);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.OccupantFileAs))
                records = records.Where(x => x.OccupantFileAs == model.OccupantFileAs);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.BuildingName))
                records = records.Where(x => x.BuildingName == model.BuildingName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CaseManager))
                records = records.Where(x => x.CaseManager == model.CaseManager);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.BuildingName))
                records = records.Where(x => x.BuildingName == model.BuildingName);

            if (model.IntakeDateStart.HasValue && model.IntakeDateEnd.HasValue)
            {
                records = records.Where(x => x.StartDate >= model.IntakeDateStart && x.StartDate <= model.IntakeDateEnd);
            }
            else
            {
                if (model.IntakeDateStart.HasValue)
                    records = records.Where(x => x.StartDate >= model.IntakeDateStart);
                if (model.IntakeDateEnd.HasValue)
                    records = records.Where(x => x.StartDate <= model.IntakeDateEnd);
            }

            if (model.ExitDateStart.HasValue && model.ExitDateEnd.HasValue)
            {
                records = records.Where(x => x.EndDate >= model.ExitDateStart && x.EndDate <= model.ExitDateEnd);
            }
            else
            {
                if (model.ExitDateStart.HasValue)
                    records = records.Where(x => x.EndDate >= model.ExitDateStart);
                if (model.ExitDateEnd.HasValue)
                    records = records.Where(x => x.EndDate <= model.ExitDateEnd);
            }

            if (model.IsActive.HasValue)
                records = records.Where(x => x.IsActive == model.IsActive);

        return records;
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are two namespaces that have the extension method name `AsEnumerable()`. Check you using namespace and remove the one redundant. If both of them are using, then you should use static style to call the `AsEnumerable` method

Comment: Also, don't post images. Copy the error text from that popup.

Comment: Why are you calling `var records = getSearchData(model);` then following up with `records = db.SpStaySearch.FromSqlRaw("dbo.SpStaySearch").AsEnumerable();` ? Which would overwrite the original results. `AsEnumerable()` would break away from the `IQueryable` implementation that the code would appear to assume it would be operating against. This looks like you've encountered a problem with an existing Linq query expression that you're trying to hack around with a direct SQL statement. Was there an error or problem *prior* to getting tied up around the `FromRawSql` and `AsEnumerable`?

Comment: @LeVu You're right, I need to use both namespace and trying to make my search function static async produces a CS0120 error on my Json & var records = getSearchData(model); I'm using System.Linq and System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Comment: @StevePy I updated my code and put var records = db.SpStaySearch.FromSqlRaw("dbo.SpStaySearch").AsEnumerable(); inside my getSearchData function but I get the same error. Previously I was getting a database operation error. SqlException: Invalid object name 'SpStaySearch'. Web tools told me that in order to apply my migrations, I needed to update my database in my PMC which I did but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Masterolu: making the `Search` function to static is not my mean. What I mean is you need to explicitly using static method `AsEnumerable`. In this case, `var records = System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable(getSearchData(model));`

Comment: @LeVu when I do that it breaks my records. I get an intellisense error saying IEnumerable<SPStaySearch> does not contain a definition for OrderBy and the best extension method overload QueryableExtension.OrderBy requires a receiver of type Iqueryable. I also get CS1061 errors for my countasync and foreachasync

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee you won't want to use `AsEnumerable()` as this would effectively materialize the entire table into memory. The original method looked like a proper approach to handling search criteria against entities. If you were getting an error that it didn't recognize SpStaySearch after a migration then the issue would most likely be that a change to either your Entity model or DB was not in sync with the other. The first thing would be to double check that your runtime environment is pointing at the expected database. From there it's looking at how mapping is configured.

Comment: My guess is that original GetSearchData method worked at some point, but you needed to make changes and then it complained about not knowing what SpStaySearch is.. Take it back to the beginning. what change did you need to make to the original which appears to have potentially renamed a table? SpStaySearch does not sound like a table name, it sounds likg a Stored Procedure name to Search a Stay Table. Something like renaming/pointing an entity at a Sproc rather than a Table is undoubtedly going to pose problems.

Comment: I updated my code. Where can I put a try & catch blocks to see error messages because I figured out that dbo.SpStaySearch could not be found. Because I had spelled it wrong, it should be dbo.spStaysSearch not dbo.SpStaySearch. Despite changing that as well as my data model name. I'm still stuck on this:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

Comment: @StevePy I believe my var count = await records.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(fase); might be the culprit but i'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: Hmm, I would revert the change  to just use the DbSet then look at the exception you get. If the issue was adding the code to get the Count, we'd need to see what exception actually occurs then.  What is the original error and on what line? Substituting awaited `async` methods with their synchronous counterparts temporarily may make it easier to debug an underlying error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237073/discussion-between-masterolu-and-steve-py).

Comment: @StevePy in this case it looks like the `spStaysSearch` is a stored procedure, in that case we _MUST_ materialise the entire result set. Just call `.ToList()` and be done with all this, we can talk about optimising the stored procedure by accepting parameters next time ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to piece together how it got to this state. My guess is that the code originally worked with tables, but new requirements came and handed to the OP with very limited EF understanding who's tried substituting what they know (possibly a sproc) rather than adjusting the existing model and now it's a tangled mess of unrelated exceptions. OP needs to go back to what was there originally and get advice on what's needed for the desired change before possibly implementing something incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var records = getSearchData(model).ToList();
 var count =  records.Count;
.....
```

You can't order records by model.SortOrder since it has nothing to do with records.
You can only do something like this

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SortOrder)) records = records.OrderBy(r=> r.Id);
```

Comment: I updated my code and the issue i'm having is this: System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side. I believe my var count = await records.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(fase); might be the culprit but i'm not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

because your source data is a Stored Procedure, you cannot compose additional query expressions over the top of it. Instead you must load it into memory, as the error suggests, by *enumerating* the result set.

> **[Including Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#including-related-data)**
> SQL Server doesn't allow composing over stored procedure calls, so any attempt to apply additional query operators to such a call will result in invalid SQL. Use AsEnumerable or AsAsyncEnumerable method right after FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated methods to make sure that EF Core doesn't try to compose over a stored procedure.

The obvious way to interpret this in the code is to call `.ToList()` on the results from the SP, then to match your existing code pattern you can cast that result back to *IQueryable*:

```
var records = db.SpStaySearches.FromSqlRaw("dbo.spStaysSearch")
                               .ToList()
                               .AsQueryable()
```

> Using `AsEnumerable()` is sometimes problematic as there are many different libraries that you may have implemented that might all provide an `AsEnumerable()` extension method.

We have to do this because even in SQL you cannot simply select from an SP and then add *where* clauses to it, you first have to read the results into a temporary table or a table variable, then you can re-query from the result set, that is what we are effectively doing now, we are reading the results into a C# variable (`.ToList()`) and then composing an in-memory query over the top of that result.

If your search logic must be encapsulated in a stored procedure, then given the technical limitations, the usual expectation is that you would add the search arguments as optional parameters to the stored procedure, rather then tring to add filter clauses on top of the results in C#.

> We can help with how to move your filter logic into `dbo.spStaysSearch` but you'll have to post the content of that SP, ideally as a new question.

---

Instead of using an SP at all, where we lose practically all the goodness that EF can offer us, an alternative approach is to replace your SP entirely with a raw SQL then the rest of your logic will work as expected.

```
var sql = @"
SELECT 
    tblStays.*, tblOccupant.OccupantID, 
    tblOccupant.FileAs AS OccupantFileAs, 
    IIF(tblStays.BuildingName LIKE 'Main Shelter',
           tblOccupant.OCFSMainNumber,
           tblOccupant.OCFSNorthNumber) AS StayOCFSNumber, 
    COALESCE([CountOfOccupantStayID], 0) AS CountOfChildren, 
    tblCaseManager.FileAs AS CaseManager,
    StaysMaxBillSentDate.MaxOfBillSentDate
FROM tblStays 
LEFT JOIN tblOccupantStays ON tblStays.StayID = tblOccupantStays.StayID
LEFT JOIN tblOccupant ON tblOccupantStays.OccupantID = tblOccupant.OccupantID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT lkpOccStays.StayID
         , COUNT(tblOccupantStays.OccupantStayID) AS CountOfOccupantStayID
    FROM tblOccupantStays lkpOccStays 
    INNER JOIN tblOccupant lkpChild ON lkpOccStays.OccupantID = lkpChild.OccupantID
    WHERE lkpChild.OccupantType LIKE 'Child'
    GROUP BY lkpOccStays.StayID
) OccupantStays_CountOfChildren ON tblStays.StayID = OccupantStays_CountOfChildren.StayID
LEFT JOIN tblCaseManager ON tblStays.CaseManagerID = tblCaseManager.CaseManagerID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tblStayBillingHx.StayID
         , MAX(tblStayBillingHx.BillSentDate) AS MaxOfBillSentDate
    FROM tblStayBillingHx 
    GROUP BY tblStayBillingHx.StayID
) StaysMaxBillSentDate ON tblStays.StayID = StaysMaxBillSentDate.StayID
";

var records = db.SpStaySearches.FromSqlRaw(sql);
```

In this way the SP is providing the structure of the resultset, which might be necessary if you are using the *Database-First* approach but you are no longer executing the SP at all.

> The SQL in this answer is provided as a guide to the syntax only, there is not enough information available to determine the validity of the query or that the results conform to your business requirements.

Comment: Are you referring to the columns within the data model or the DBSet of the SP? And how would I link that new post so you can find it?

Comment: No I mean the SP SQL script, you would need to modify the SP to accept the parameters and do something with them, another alternative is to replace the SP entirely with an EF/Linq query, then you can manage it in the code. A solution that executes the SP into memory and then applies a filter is generally an anti-pattern that will lead to poor performance. Just post the link to the new question as a response to this comment ;)

Comment: Here is my SP script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198210/how-to-pass-parameters-into-this-stored-procedure

Comment: @Masterolu Having seen your SP now, I have to ask why you are using an SP at all? That would be a simpler to compose in linq.

Comment: I honestly don't know, I asked my team and they said if I want to do it in Linq I can

Comment: Using stored procedures is usually mandated by a team of DBAs who want to control the data execution, or when your codebase spans multiple runtimes that all access the database directly. In a .Net ecosystem we generally don't need to operate like that anymore and either have a central API or a shared data access library, so if there isn't a rich set of SPs then I wouldn't use them, especially not for this, not when you want to use composable queries and delayed execution.