# How to pass parameters into this stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156205/why-does-asenumerable-not-work-when-using-fromsqlraw/69179272) I tried to call a Stored Procedure via EntityFramework and then filter on the results.

How would I move my filter logic into `dbo.spStaysSearch` so I can modify the stored procedure to accept parameters?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStaysSearch] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        tblOccupantStays.StayID, 
        COUNT(tblOccupantStays.OccupantStayID) AS CountOfOccupantStayID
    INTO 
        #OccupantStays_CountOfChildren
    FROM 
        tblOccupantStays 
    INNER JOIN 
        tblOccupant ON tblOccupantStays.OccupantID = tblOccupant.OccupantID
    WHERE 
        (((tblOccupant.OccupantType) LIKE 'Child'))
    GROUP BY 
        tblOccupantStays.StayID;

    SELECT 
        tblOccupant.OccupantID, tblOccupant.OccupantType
    INTO 
        #OccupantsAdults
    FROM 
        tblOccupant
    WHERE 
        (((tblOccupant.OccupantType) = 'Adult'));

    SELECT 
        tblStayBillingHx.StayID, 
        MAX(tblStayBillingHx.BillSentDate) AS MaxOfBillSentDate
    INTO 
        #StaysMaxBillSentDate
    FROM 
        tblStayBillingHx 
    GROUP BY 
        tblStayBillingHx.StayID;
 
    SELECT 
        tblStays.*, tblOccupant.OccupantID, 
        tblOccupant.FileAs AS OccupantFileAs, 
        IIF(tblStays.BuildingName LIKE 'Main Shelter',
               tblOccupant.OCFSMainNumber,
               tblOccupant.OCFSNorthNumber) AS StayOCFSNumber, 
        COALESCE([CountOfOccupantStayID], 0) AS CountOfChildren, 
        tblCaseManager.FileAs AS CaseManager,
        #StaysMaxBillSentDate.MaxOfBillSentDate
    FROM 
        (((((tblStays 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblOccupantStays ON tblStays.StayID = tblOccupantStays.StayID) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblOccupant ON tblOccupantStays.OccupantID = tblOccupant.OccupantID) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        #OccupantStays_CountOfChildren ON tblStays.StayID = #OccupantStays_CountOfChildren.StayID) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        #OccupantsAdults ON tblOccupant.OccupantID = #OccupantsAdults.OccupantID)
    LEFT JOIN 
        tblCaseManager ON tblStays.CaseManagerID = tblCaseManager.CaseManagerID) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        #StaysMaxBillSentDate ON tblStays.StayID = #StaysMaxBillSentDate.StayID
    ORDER BY 
        tblStays.StartDate, tblOccupant.FileAs;
END
```

Currently calling from this C#

```
private IQueryable<spStaysSearch> getSearchData(StaySearchViewModel model)
{
   var records = db.SpStaySearches.FromSqlRaw("dbo.spStaysSearch").ToList().AsQueryable();

    if (model.OccupantId.HasValue)
        records = records.Where(x => x.OccupantId == model.OccupantId);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.OccupantFileAs))
        records = records.Where(x => x.OccupantFileAs == model.OccupantFileAs);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.BuildingName))
        records = records.Where(x => x.BuildingName == model.BuildingName);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.CaseManager))
        records = records.Where(x => x.CaseManager == model.CaseManager);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.BuildingName))
        records = records.Where(x => x.BuildingName == model.BuildingName);

    if (model.IntakeDateStart.HasValue && model.IntakeDateEnd.HasValue)
    {
        records = records.Where(x => x.StartDate >= model.IntakeDateStart && x.StartDate <= model.IntakeDateEnd);
    }
    else
    {
        if (model.IntakeDateStart.HasValue)
            records = records.Where(x => x.StartDate >= model.IntakeDateStart);
        if (model.IntakeDateEnd.HasValue)
            records = records.Where(x => x.StartDate <= model.IntakeDateEnd);
    }

    if (model.ExitDateStart.HasValue && model.ExitDateEnd.HasValue)
    {
        records = records.Where(x => x.EndDate >= model.ExitDateStart && x.EndDate <= model.ExitDateEnd);
    }
    else
    {
        if (model.ExitDateStart.HasValue)
            records = records.Where(x => x.EndDate >= model.ExitDateStart);
        if (model.ExitDateEnd.HasValue)
            records = records.Where(x => x.EndDate <= model.ExitDateEnd);
    }

    if (model.IsActive.HasValue)
        records = records.Where(x => x.IsActive == model.IsActive);
    return records;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from doing it in the normal way - declaring them after `CREATE PROCEDURE` and before `AS` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/parameters).  I'm not sure what the C# aspect of this question is.

Comment: CTEs might make this a far simpler execution plan, this type of lookup can be done in a single query without allocating temporary tables, as a search routine, its one of those places where performance actually matters

Comment: @ChrisSchaller can you elaborate on this or provide an example? This is still new to me

Comment: @Flydog57 my apologies I was referring to this C# code. I'm getting this exception thrown at var count = await records.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(fase);

System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

Comment: @Masterolu Try not to post the same detail from your previous question, keep this question focused on moving the parameters, as this will solve your current exception, its just this in this question we will solve it in a different way.

Comment: When you use EF in the standard way, you get a queryable back that you can use to compose other queryables. If I say `var q = from a in apples where a.color == Color.Green; var qq = q.Where(a => a.Size != Size.Small);`.  It will take `q` and compose a further query (`qq`) that includes stuff from both statements.  It can do that because it can translate the composed query back into SQL.  in your case, you are starting in raw SQL that the EF magic doesn't understand. It can't tack on the rest of your query-ish code. Materialize the result from the original query and then work from there

Comment: Did you write this code or inherit it, there is duplication and redundancy meaning this whole thing could be cleared right up.

Comment: What is the purpose of `#OccupantsAdults`? It does not participate in filtering or sorting, is not projected in the selected columns and does not contribute any additional records in the result. This can be taken out entirely. Or is that supposed to be an INNER JOIN, which would make only the Adult occupant records returned in the search results.

Comment: If the query is wrong in the first place, then even if we fix issues here, you will end up in the XY paradox: https://xyproblem.info/ so I ask that you confirm the SP as it stands now provides the recordset that you are expecting. Right now you get 1 row for every occupant, even if they are an adult or a child, but each of those rows has a count of children, meaning if you sum the child counts for a family of 6, you will get a total of 24 children.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues to unpack

1. Adding parameters to an SP is as simple as declaring them according to this guide: [SQL Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/parameters)
2. Passing parameters to an SP from C# is described here [EF Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)
3. Your SP can be improved and replaced with a composable query which mean you no longer have to pass parameters through at all

### How to Define the Parameters in your SP:

*Lets do just the first 2 for now...*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStaysSearch] 
    @OccupantId INT,
    @OccupantFileAs VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
...
```

But then you need to use those parameters in your query, one way to do that is adding filter clauses like this to your select statement:

```
WHERE (@OccupantId IS NULL OR tblOccupant.OccupantID = @OccupantId)
  AND (@OccupantFileAs IS NULL OR tblOccupant.FileAs = @OccupantFileAs)
```

### How to Pass C# parameters to an SP via EF

```
var records = db.SpStaySearches.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.spStaysSearch @OccupantId, @OccupantFileAs")
                                   ,new SqlParameter("OccupantId", model.OccupantId)
                                   ,new SqlParameter("OccupantFileAs", model.OccupantFileAs)
                               .ToList()
                               .AsQueryable();
```

### Replace the SP altogether

There is no benefit in this case to using a stored procedure at all, the SP is not performing any logical operations, it is merely a wrapper around a very simple query. There are 2 ways we can replace this stored procedure call:

1. replace the SP with actual raw SQL:

   ***NOTE:** To be composable we cannot use CTEs, it must be a valid SQL expression that can be called as a nested or inline query*

   ```
   var sql = @"
    SELECT 
        tblStays.*, tblOccupant.OccupantID, 
        tblOccupant.FileAs AS OccupantFileAs, 
        IIF(tblStays.BuildingName LIKE 'Main Shelter',
               tblOccupant.OCFSMainNumber,
               tblOccupant.OCFSNorthNumber) AS StayOCFSNumber, 
        COALESCE([CountOfOccupantStayID], 0) AS CountOfChildren, 
        tblCaseManager.FileAs AS CaseManager,
        StaysMaxBillSentDate.MaxOfBillSentDate
    FROM tblStays 
    LEFT JOIN tblOccupantStays ON tblStays.StayID = tblOccupantStays.StayID
    LEFT JOIN tblOccupant ON tblOccupantStays.OccupantID = tblOccupant.OccupantID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT lkpOccStays.StayID
             , COUNT(tblOccupantStays.OccupantStayID) AS CountOfOccupantStayID
        FROM tblOccupantStays lkpOccStays 
        INNER JOIN tblOccupant lkpChild ON lkpOccStays.OccupantID = lkpChild.OccupantID
        WHERE lkpChild.OccupantType LIKE 'Child'
        GROUP BY lkpOccStays.StayID
    ) OccupantStays_CountOfChildren ON tblStays.StayID = OccupantStays_CountOfChildren.StayID
    LEFT JOIN tblCaseManager ON tblStays.CaseManagerID = tblCaseManager.CaseManagerID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tblStayBillingHx.StayID
             , MAX(tblStayBillingHx.BillSentDate) AS MaxOfBillSentDate
        FROM tblStayBillingHx 
        GROUP BY tblStayBillingHx.StayID
    ) StaysMaxBillSentDate ON tblStays.StayID = StaysMaxBillSentDate.StayID       
   ";
   var records = db.SpStaySearches.FromSqlRaw(sql);
   ```
2. You could do this entirely in Linq:

   *A **LOT** of assumptions are made here, your EF schema has not been provided so some conventions have been assumed, this specific query may not match your schema but it should be close enough to understand the concept.*

   ```
    var records = db.Stays.SelectMany(s => s.Occupants.Select(o => new spStaysSearch {
        StayId = s.StayId,
        ... (other stays properties)
        OccupantId = o.OccupantId,
        OccupantFileAs = o.FileAs,
        StayOCFSNumber = s.BuildingName == "Main Shelter" ? o.OCFSMainNumber : o.OCFSNorthNumber,
        CountOfChildren = s.Occupants.Count(child => child.OccupantType == "Child"),
        CaseManager = s.CaseManager.FileAs,
        MaxOfBillSentDate = s.BillingHistory.Max(h => h.BillSentDate)
    }));
   ```